# Rails 3 - Can I set start date to date_select method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

date_select method can only set :start_year, but i'd like to set start date (e.g. date 3 months ago) (but there are no such options).

so, can i set start date to date_select method?
or, to make such the select box, should i use select_tag and options_for_select?
or, are there any solutions?

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date_select` helper only supports setting a `start_year` and `end_year` (i.e. 2015-2020), not a `start_date` and `end_date` (i.e. June 1st, 2015 to July 1st, 2020). The `date_select` helper is design to be very simple. If you look closely, you will even notice every month has 31 days.

A few workarounds are available:

1. Do validations on the server side and present errors if dates are submitted that are outside an acceptable range.
2. Switch to using a JavaScript client - such as http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/ - that allows limiting the start and end (should still use server side validations as well).

Comment: oh, i see. i'll think about doing validations on the server side. thanks for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @KevinSylvestre, you can set the :start_year. I have it many places in my code and it works.

Comment: @Jay Yes you can. The original question even states this. My answer states that you can not specify a start **date** (as in starting May 2, 2010) without the use of JavaScript and not with the default date_select method.

Comment: I don't understand why anybody had downvoted this answer.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible... e.g.

:start_year – Set the start year for the year select. Default is Time.now.year - 5

see [this resource](http://selvaonrails.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/date_select/).