# Specify date range with Rails `date_select`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to specify a date range using the Rails [date_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) form helper. For example, I want the available options to be from today through, say, the end of the week. I know you can specify `end_year`, but I'm needing to specify a specific date.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140937/rails-3-can-i-set-start-date-to-date-select-method

Comment: @Arv Ah, I saw that but I guess glanced over it at first since it had 2 down votes. Thanks.