# Haml generating Form from a Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, haml

I'm making a rails app and making a form in HAML. I'm using the database to generate the from.

```
    .form-inputs
      =f.input :name
      =f.input :DOB
      =f.input :FavSport
```

And the DOB is in the database as `date` so the menu rails generates for that field is for the future dates not previous dates.
How I get the dropdown menu to be for previous years not future?
Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140937/rails-3-can-i-set-start-date-to-date-select-method

Comment: there aren't code examples on this

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using Simple Form which delegates `date` inputs to the built on rails `date_select` form input helper.

The `date_select` helper provides the `start_year` and `end_year` options which you can use as so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                              end_year: Date.today.year - 12, discard_day: true,
                              order: [:month, :year] %>
  <%= f.input :accepts, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form